# Bootstrap panel-heading with vertical-middle char/icon

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can I get the x positioned vertical middle when displaying on small devices (< 600px width)?

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <section class="panel panel-default panel-slider"><div class="panel-heading">
      <h1 class="panel-title" style="font-size:18px">
           Test with long description in title panel bla bla<a class="align-middle more pull-right" href="https://example.com" title="" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" data-original-title="more" ><i>x</i></a>
      </h1>
</div>
 <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="row">
           <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
           ...
      </div>
</div>
```

Currently it is:

[image]

Should be:

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/9dtu4en1/

Thanks in advance!

Kind regards
Alex

Comment: you are using bootstrap 3 not 4

Answer (score 1):

I'd use flexbox on that `h1` for a more fluid resizing, and remove `align-middle` & `pull-right` (to avoid floating which would make it's parent not consider child's height) from `a`:

**[External Fiddle to resize](https://jsfiddle.net/9dtu4en1/3/)**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Snippet:

```css
h1 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <section class="panel panel-default panel-slider">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h1 class="panel-title" style="font-size:18px">Test with long description in title panel bla bla
          <a class="more" href="https://example.com" title="" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" data-original-title="more"><i>x</i></a>
        </h1>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
            ...
          </div>
        </div>
```